# Why is $\cos 2x$ equal to $2\cos^2x-1$ and $1-2\sin^2 x$?

Tags: trigonometry

How come the following trigonometric identity is true?

\begin{align}
\cos(2x) &= \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) \quad\text{(I understand how they got this)} \\
&= 2\cos^2(x) - 1 \\
&= 1 - 2\sin^2(x).
\end{align}

I understand how they arrived at the first line of math:

Let $a = b = x$, then

\begin{align}
\cos(x+x) &= \cos(x)\cos(x) - \sin(x)\sin(x) \\
\cos(2x) &= \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)
\end{align}

But after that I do not understand.

Thank you and have a great day,

Joseph Cummens

Comment: Remember that $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ by the pythagorean theorem.  So, $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)+1-1 = \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)-1=\dots$  Remember you can always "add zero" or "multiply by one" and it won't change anything.  The trick is what "zero" or "one" look like in your specific situation.

Comment: I am a flipping idiot. I forgot about that formula. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos 2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x \tag1$$ $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\tag2$$

Make use of these two formulas twice once by substituting in another expression for $\sin^2x$ and then for $\cos^2x$ into the first identity.